# Why can't you use m-CPBA to synthesise isophorone oxide from isophorone?

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbonyl-compounds

Apparently you must use sodium hydroxide and hydrogen peroxide because using m-CPBA gives an undesired product

[image]

Why doesn't m-CPBA work and what does it do instead? Why does sodium hydroxide and hydrogen peroxide work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using MCPBA, the undesired by-product is probably formed due to Baeyer–Villiger oxidation of the ketone to the corresponding ester (here: lactone).

Comment: and why doesn't this happen with the peroxide?

Comment: Iirc the Dakin oxidation of a ketone generally only works with benzaldehydes or acetophenones with EDGs o- or p- to the carbonyl